# How do I enable ALPN and TLS session resumption (client tickets) in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: https, windows

According to the following TechNet article ALPN and TLS client-side session resumption should be supported in SChannel in Windows Server 2012 R2.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831771.aspx

We've just upgraded our webserver to 2012 R2 but SSLLabs shows these features as still not supported.  Are there any extra steps required to enable them with IIS 8.5?  Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

To enable TLS session tickets on win2k12 r2 and win2k16, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a key (DWORD) in registry with value 1 HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\EnableSslSessionTicket
2. Create a new TLS session ticket key through this powershell command: New-TlsSessionTicketKey -Password  -Path "C:\KeyConfig\TlsSessionTicketKey.config" -ServiceAccountName "System" 
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/tls/new-tlssessionticketkey
3. Enable TLS session ticket key through this powershell command: Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey -Password  -Path "C:\KeyConfig\TlsSessionTicketKey.config" -ServiceAccountName "System"
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/tls/enable-tlssessionticketkey
4. Reboot the server to enable TLS session ticket generation. Reboot is required for the registry entry to take effect.

Thanks,

Vinayak

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this in their efforts to address an F grade on SSLLabs after May 1st, note that step one of Vinayak's post above can be flipped to a 0 and the rest disregarded to turn off session tickets. It appears that a 2012R2 box we have is running a mail server (Smartermail) on it and was getting flagged that it would fail the Ticketbleed portion after May 1st 2017.

As mentioned since this is a registry change a reboot is required to apply.